# UITableView willDisplayCell - something strange is going on

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uitableview

I have my datasource (productsArry) which is populated via SQLite and I'm fetching 25 items at a time. I'm calling the 'willDisplayCell' UITableView delegate and when the indexPath.row is equal to the productsArry count it will fetch new data and reload the tables view. This works great with no problems but lets say if the datasource has 100 objects, which are being displayed in the tableview and then the productsArry has been filtered with less objects (say 50) and do a reloadData, which is fine again, but the problem is within the willDisplayCell delegate. For some reason this method is being called without the user scrolling. So it thinks cell 25 has been scrolled too so now it will fetch the next set of rows from the database. It will keep on doing this until it reaches the 100 objects from the last set of data or theres nothing else to fetch from the filter.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (([self.productsArry count] != 0) && (indexPath.row == [self.productsArry count])) 
    {
        self.currentOffset += TableviewRowCount;
        [self performSelector:@selector(reloadTableView:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
    }
}

- (void)reloadTableView:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"reloadtable");
    [self fetchData];
    [self.productTableView reloadData];
}
```

Please let me know if you need to know anything else that might help to clear things up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing is reloading the entire table, cells and all, when you call reloadData.  That's why willDisplayCell gets called -- it'll get called for all the visible cells. It's probably not a good idea to do this at that time.  What you want to do is just reload a section of the table that's new - look at reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: instead.  Most apps don't do an automatic get when they get to the end of a list, they have the last cell be a button, or ask the user to bounce the list (a la Facebook) to add more content.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. @OwenHartenett could You please tell me, how can I call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths right after fetching data from server.

Comment: willDisplayCell shouldn't be called for every cell in the table. Omar's answer below is the correct one. You need an estimated height for the initial layout to prevent it from being called for more cells than necessary.

Answer (score 7):

I found the main issue here is that the table does not know the height of the cell so it assume the default of OS and the cell will be disabled , after the table calculate the layout it get the correct height.

So to fix this issue just add the

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100 // or your estimate
```